# Django rest framework foreign key returning as Integer

Tags: django, vue.js, django-models, django-rest-framework, xmlhttprequest

I tried to serialize a model in django with drf but now the problem I am facing is that the author which is a foreign key is being returned as an Integer. I am using Vue.js as frontend. Someone please help

Serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post

class PostSerialiers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerialiers
from rest_framework import viewsets

class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerialiers

def Home(request):
    return render(request, 'Content/Home.html')
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=1200, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Template:

```
<div v-for="post in obj" style="width: 100%;" class="ui card">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">[[post.title]]</div>
        <div class="meta">2 days ago</div>
        <div class="description">
          <p>[[post.caption]]</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="extra content">
        <i class="check icon"></i>
        [[post.author]]
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function loadDoc() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var app = new Vue({
              el: '#root',
              delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
              data:{
                "obj" : JSON.parse(this.responseText)
              }
            
          })
          }
        }
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8000/apiposts/', true);
        xhr.send()
      }

      loadDoc()

    </script>
```

Someone please help

Comment: use depth=1 in class meta if you want that post author full details then you can use in html as post.author.first_name or post.author.last_name, post.author.email

Comment: @giveJob no, it's not working

Comment: did you check through postman? depth=1 should work  if you add below the fields = "__all__", or any error?

Comment: @giveJob no I did not

Comment: @giveJob please help if you can. I have been struggling with this for past 1 month or so

Comment: set [**`depth=1`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) in your serializer.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu if I set the depth=1 it shows all the details like Id, password, Last login, email etc

Comment: then use a nested serializer and specify the fields that are needed

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes it's working now. I mean it's doing what I wanted it to do. I just needed to add post.author.username after setting depth = 1 but now one more problem arose. The option to choose author in the api endpoint is gone. What to do? I am not able to upload new post since not null constraint is failling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cretae a new `serializer` for `User`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        # if you want more fields you can include them
        fields = ('username',)
```

You will have to create a new `serializer` for `Post` model, because while retrieving you are looking for `username` or `email` (whatever you are using) and then again while creating a new `Post` you want out of the box functionality to `select` a user from your database. Ideally it's not possible because under the hood `ForeignKey` uses `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and when you will try to get `username` by setting author to `UserSerializer()` in `PostSerializer`, something like this:

```
class PostSerialiers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','caption','author']
```

You will loose the out of box functionality to add `User` on `Post`. Because now you will be dealing with the `fields` defined in `UserSerializer`. And if you don't do any of this; under the hood it will use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and it will give you the option to choose `User` while creating `Post` and you will loose `username` while retrieving the data. If you look objectively you want both of the functionality in same `ViewSet`. So you can have two different `serializer` for two different purposes.

```
class PostSerialiers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # this serializer will deal with creating Post with option to select User
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"


class NewPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # this serializer will deal with retrieving data with username/email
    author = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```

Finally in your `PostView` you need override `list()` because while retrieving you want `username` instead of `pk` so you will need to use the `serializer` which deals with `username` which is `NewPostSerializer`.

`views.py`

```
class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerialiers

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = NewPostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Serializer.py, change this:

```
class PostSerialiers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```

to this:

```
class PostSerialiers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','caption','author']
```

Comment: But it's not letting me associate the user with the post. I mean when I try to upload a new post the option to choose author is missing